# Setting an imageview src through an activity

Tags: android

I keep trying to set an imageview through my main activity and it keeps returning a null pointer exception in LogCat. My code is fairly self explanatory.

I'm pulling data from a JSON url and pulling data out of objects.

```
for (int i=0; i<forecastday_arr.length(); i++) {                        
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
    JSONObject e = forecastday_arr.getJSONObject(i);

    JSONObject date_obj = e.getJSONObject("date");

    String curDate = date_obj.getString("weekday");
    String conditions = e.getString("conditions");
    String icon_to_use = e.getString("icon");

    map.put("weekday", curDate);
    map.put("conditions", conditions);
    map.put("icon", icon_to_use);

    if (icon_to_use=="rain") {
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDayOne);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.rain));
    }      

    mylist.add(map);    
}
```

From my code I'm checking to see if the value in "icon" is equal to rain, which it is (today), and if so, return the rain icon that's stored in my drawable folder. Even without the if statement I get the same null pointer exception. I'm quite new to Android so debugging isn't the easiest thing right now.

I presume I'm setting the image correctly. I've attached a picture of my LogCat below.[image]

Sorry to be so vague but I thought it would be really simple to set an image. I'm sorry if I've missed anything as well - if I have I will quickly correct.

Pastebin of my MainActivity.java: http://pastebin.com/uNfYDGAw and a pastebin of my activity_main.xml: http://pastebin.com/M1xy1buB

Comment: what is written on line 61 of MainActivity.

Comment: imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.rain));

Comment: @Xiy : make sure u have an ImageView with imageViewDayOne id in layout which u are using for MainActivity

Comment: I do. I'm sure it would complain and give me a syntax error if not. There's definitely an image holder and there's definitely an image available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears your `NullPointerException` is coming from this line:

```
    imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.rain));
```

I suspect that either `this.getResources()` or more likely `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` is returning `null`.

Luckily for you, there is an easier way to set an image on an `ImageView`. You can use [`setImageResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) to set the drawable resource at runtime, like this:

```
    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rain);
```

### **--EDIT--**

You also need to make sure you call `setContentView` with the layout that contains the `ImageView` you are attempting to use in `onCreate` of you `MainActivity`, **before** trying to reference any `View`s using `findViewById`.

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoutContainingImageViewDayOne);
```

Lastly, if you are attempting to do any network requests, they should be done in a background thread (off the UI thread) or the application with get an "Application Not Responding" crash. `AsyncTask`s are useful for this (however there are other methods). See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html for more info.

### **--EDIT 2--**

So now that you posted all of the code, I see there are some major flaws here. Your `R.layout.activity_main` should actually be renamed to `R.layout.list_row` since it contains your row elements. Right now you are trying to use the same layout (`R.layout.activity_main`) for your `Activity` and its `ListAdapter`, which is impossible. `R.layout.activity_main` needs to have a `ListView` in it, that you attach your `ListAdapter` to. You are also trying to set your `ImageView` in your `Activity` code for your list rows, which the `ListAdapter` will already do for you.

So I'm going to suggest you take a look at some examples and refactor your app, Vogella has some great tutorials - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html.

Comment: It still gives me a null pointer. Here's a picture of my logcat: http://oi46.tinypic.com/2wnwarc.jpg

Comment: @Xiy : if it still giving then im 100% sure ImageView is null or you are trying to use findViewById in wrong place just post layout xml and whole activity code to find issue quickly thanks

Comment: What is on MainActivity line 60 now? imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rain);? If so, it's probably that the id you are trying to get is not in the layout you have. Make sure `setContentView` is using the layout that has this `ImageView` with `R.id.imageViewDayOne`.

Comment: Can it not be null as it's going to be populated? Or does it have to be populated with *any* image until the main activity is ran and the image changes? I've populated the SRC of ImageView and I still get the same error.

Comment: Line 60: imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rain); I've uploaded my MainActivity.java here: http://pastebin.com/uNfYDGAw

Comment: @Xiy yes it is null because `findViewById(R.id.imageViewDayOne)` isn't finding it in the layout your `Activity` sets in `setContentView`, and returning `null`. Then you are trying to set the image on a `null` `ImageView` object, and **BOOM** crash. Post your whole layout and `Activity` in the question and we will be able to spot the error.

Comment: @Xiy : where u are setting layout for Activity  using setContentView? because im not able to find this line in MainActivity code

Comment: Sorry, I set it on line 28: setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder); - but in the pastebin I removed it just to test. Updated.

Comment: Just edited the question, sorry for the confusion. I've added my layout and main activity file.

Answer (score 0):

First use `equals` method to compare the Strings. Instead of ==

```
if (icon_to_use != null && icon_to_use.equals("rain")) {

   ....

}
```

> Cause of NullPointerException

It might be because of you did not call setContentView to the layout or did not set right layout. means `imageViewDayOne` is not define in that layout.

Comment: @Xiy have your problem solved make accept the answer whichever you like.